# My laravel project but some data not sound in query

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, query-builder

```php
    public function plan($id){
        $video = DB::select("SELECT * FROM `video` WHERE `video_episod` = ".$id." ");
        dd($video);
        return view('users.subplan', ['plan' => $plan]);
     }

    dd($video);
    result : []
```

Comment: use this code:   return view('users.subplan',['video'=>$video]);

Comment: [The docs aren't clear](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queries#selects)?

Answer (score 1):

If you expect multiple records in response then use `get();`

```
$videos = DB::table('video')->where('video_episod',$id)->get();
```

If you expect only one record in response then use `first();`

```
$video = DB::table('video')->where('video_episod',$id)->first();
```

Comment: are you sure that your `video_episod` field is matched with `$id`? can you `dd($id)` and check that id is in video_episod exist or not?

Answer (score 0):

you can't do it like that. `DB::select()` is for the column that you want to select. if you want a raw query to run in laravel you need to do it like this

```
public function plan($id){

        $video = DB::raw("SELECT * FROM `video` WHERE `video_episod` = ".$id." ");

        dd($video);

        return view('users.subplan',['plan'=>$plan]);
    }

dd($video);
```

**or like this**

```
public function plan($id){

            $video = DB::select(DB::raw("SELECT * FROM `video` WHERE `video_episod` = ".$id." "));

            dd($video);

            return view('users.subplan',['plan'=>$plan]);
        }

    dd($video);
```

just try both of them. im not entirely sure.

hope it helps.

Comment: I think you typo your column `video_episod` to `video_episode`

Comment: I updated it to `video_episode` if its still not found data maybe you can check if your `$id` has a value.

Comment: no...database name same "video_episod" Result: Collection {#326 ▼
  #items: []
}

Comment: does the `$id` has a value? try to `dd()` it